# Groovy AstBuilder use argumentList for method params

Tags: groovy, abstract-syntax-tree

I want to add the following `if`-statement at the beginning of a method:

```
@Grant( [ Permission.admin ] )
def someMethod( someArg ){
  if( GrantUtil.checkAuthorization( someArg, Permission.admin ){ // 2nd param comes from annotation
    // nothing
  }else{
    return null
  }

  // the rest
}
```

For that I'm using a custom ASTTransformation:

```
class GrantASTTransformation implements ASTTransformation {
  
  @Override
  void visit( ASTNode[] nodes, SourceUnit source ) {
    if( !nodes ) return
    
    MethodNode methodNode = (MethodNode) nodes.find{ it in MethodNode }
    
    if( methodNode ) augmentMethod methodNode
  }

  void augmentMethod( MethodNode methodNode ) {       
    List<AnnotationNode> annos = methodNode.getAnnotations new ClassNode( Grant )
    Expression rolesValue = annos.first().getMember 'value'
    
    Expression param = new VariableExpression( methodNode.parameters[ 0 ] )

    Expression args = new ArgumentListExpression( [ param, rolesValue ] )
    StaticMethodCallExpression callExp = new StaticMethodCallExpression( new ClassNode( GrantUtil ), 'checkAuthorization', args )
    BooleanExpression checkExpression = new BooleanExpression( callExp )

    IfStatement ifStmt = new IfStatement( checkExpression, new EmptyStatement(), new ReturnStatement( ConstantExpression.NULL ) )
  
    ((BlockStatement)methodNode.code).statements.add 0, ifStmt
  }
}
```

and it works like charm.

Now I want to rewrite this method using a more transparent AstBuilder and so far I came out with:

```
void augmentMethod( MethodNode methodNode ) {       
  List<AnnotationNode> annos = methodNode.getAnnotations new ClassNode( Grant )
  Expression rolesValue = annos.first().getMember 'value'
  
  IfStatement ifStmt = (IfStatement)new AstBuilder().buildFromSpec{
      ifStatement{
        booleanExpression{
          staticMethodCall( GrantUtil, 'checkAuthorization' ){
            argumentList{ 
              // this doesn't work
              param
              rolesValue
            }
          }
        }
        //if block
        empty()
        //else block
        returnStatement{ constant null }
      }
  }.first()
    
  ((BlockStatement)methodNode.code).statements.add 0, ifStmt
}
```

but it fails filling up the `argumentList`, throwing

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static GrantUtil.checkAuthorization() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: checkAuthorization(io.vertx.ext.web.RoutingContext, java.util.List)
```

I looked through the [test](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/test/org/codehaus/groovy/ast/builder/AstBuilderFromSpecificationTest.groovy) but could not find a way to introduce the "external" params to the `argumentList`.

What is the proper way of doing this? Is this supported by the AstBuilder?

UPDATE:

I tried the suggestion of @cfrick and it worked to 50%:

```
staticMethodCall(GrantUtil, 'checkAuthorization') {
  argumentList {
    variable methodNode.parameters[0].name // works like charm!
    constant( [ Permission.user ] as Permission[] )
  }
}
```

Now upon execution I'm getting the exception:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
General error during instruction selection: Cannot generate bytecode for constant: [Lio.lootwalk.domain.Permission;@1e7f19b4 of type: [Lio.lootwalk.domain.Permission;
```

So, passing an array of Enumeration object as a `constant` in `argumentList` fails...

Comment: Would you mind adding or linking the whole ASTTransformation class (e.g. the class `augmentMethod` is in)?

Comment: added the `visit()` method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can improve your original solution using the static methods in Groovy's `GeneralUtils` class:

```
class GrantASTTransformation implements ASTTransformation {
    @Override
    void visit(ASTNode[] nodes, SourceUnit source ) {
        nodes?.find{ it in MethodNode }?.with{ augmentMethod it }
    }

    void augmentMethod( MethodNode mn ) {
        def annos = mn.getAnnotations new ClassNode( Grant )
        def rolesValue = annos.first().getMember 'value'
        def param = varX( mn.parameters[ 0 ] )

        def args = args( param, rolesValue )
        def callCheck = callX( new ClassNode( GrantUtil ), 'checkAuthorization', args )
        def notAuthorized = notX( boolX( callCheck ) )
        def returnEarly = returnS( nullX() )

        def guard = ifS( notAuthorized, returnEarly )
        mn.code.statements.add 0, guard
    }
}
```

With regards to `AstBuilder`, it is now less favoured than its replacement, macros. One way to use macros to write the `augmentMethod` is:

```
void augmentMethod( MethodNode mn ) {
    def grantNode = ClassHelper.make(Grant)
    def grantUtilNode = ClassHelper.make(GrantUtil)
    def annos = mn.getAnnotations grantNode
    def rolesValue = annos.first().getMember 'value'
    def param = varX( mn.parameters[ 0 ] )
    def guard = macro {
        if (!$v{ classX(grantUtilNode) }.checkAuthorization( $v{ param }, $v{ rolesValue } )) {
            return
        }
    }
    mn.code.statements.add 0, guard
}
```

You just have to be careful with referencing classes within that code which is why `GrantUtil` doesn't appear explicitly.

To stick with `AstBuilder` you can use:

```
void augmentMethod( MethodNode mn ) {
    def annos = mn.getAnnotations new ClassNode( Grant )
    def rolesValue = annos.first().getMember('value').expressions[0]
    def param = varX( mn.parameters[ 0 ] )
    def guard = new AstBuilder().buildFromSpec {
        ifStatement{
            booleanExpression{
                staticMethodCall( GrantUtil, 'checkAuthorization' ) {
                    argumentList {
                        variable param.name
                        property {
                            classExpression rolesValue.objectExpression.type.typeClass
                            constant rolesValue.propertyAsString
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            empty()
            returnStatement{ constant null }
        }
    }.first()
    mn.code.statements.add 0, guard
}
```

There is probably a simplification possible but the above works.

Comment: Thanks! picked the `GeneralUtils` solution for it's simplicity -> works like charm!

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the error is that the closure passed to `argumentList` is
basically a no-op.  You can write whatever (non DSL) code you want
there, but it will not have any direct influence on the generated code;
hence the error about the missing arguments to the final call at
runtime.

You have to use the verbs of the DSL to actually create arguments.  In
your case those are `variable` and `constant`.

This is generating the correct code:

```
staticMethodCall(GrantUtil, 'checkAuthorization') {
    argumentList {
        variable methodNode.parameters[0].name
        constant AbstractASTTransformation.getMemberStringValue(annos.first(), 'value')
    }
}
```

#### edit

For the records the version to make it work with enum arrays:

```
static void augmentMethod(MethodNode methodNode) {
    List<AnnotationNode> annos = methodNode.getAnnotations new ClassNode(Grant)

    IfStatement ifStmt = (IfStatement) new AstBuilder().buildFromSpec {
        ifStatement {
            booleanExpression {
                staticMethodCall(GrantUtil, 'checkAuthorization') {
                    argumentList {
                        variable methodNode.parameters[0].name
                        expression << makeList(annos.first(), 'value')
                    }
                }
            }
            // then
            empty()
            // else
            returnStatement { constant null }
        }
    }.first()

    ((BlockStatement) methodNode.code).statements.add 0, ifStmt
}

static ListExpression makeList(AnnotationNode annotation, String name) {
    Expression expr = annotation.getMember(name)
    if (expr == null) {
        return null
    }
    if (expr instanceof ListExpression) {
        return expr
    }
    return new ListExpression([expr])
}
```

This just assures, that there is always a list literal around and then
just takes whatever is in there; then we can just take that as
expression as is.

This works for:

```
@Grant([Permission.user, Permission.anon])
@Grant(Permission.admin)
```

Comment: thanks, the 1st arg with `variable` works! The 2nd arg of `checkAuthorization()` is a `List<Permission>`, not a single String -> I'm always getting `null` instead

Comment: Have you tried `AbstractASTTransformation.getMemberList` instead?

Comment: it returns a `List<String>`, which is not compatible...

Comment: So `GrantUtil.checkAuthorization` takes `String[]`?  Oddly there is no helper for `String[]` beside the member helpers. If you can not find one, I'd copy `getMemberList` and return the array.

Comment: no, the method looks like that: `boolean checkAuthorization( RoutingContext rc, List<Permission> grants )` or `checkAuthorization( RoutingContext rc, Permission[] grants )`

Comment: Is `Grant` and/or `Permission` anywhere publicly available?

Comment: Yes, `Permission` enum is everywhere available. See also the update please and the exception...